# Invalid Account for Campaign Nexmo

Tags: php, vonage

I want to send Campaign message using nexmo. I have nexmo account and using the following code to send messages to the list in to. but I get response 101 Invalid Account for Campaign.

```
$nx_mkt_uri = "https://rest.nexmo.com/sc/us/alert/json"; 
$data = array('to' => $to, 'time' => $message,);   
$data = array_merge($data, array('api_key' => 'xxxxxxxx', 'api_secret' => "xxxxxxxx"));
$post = '';
foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
    $post .= "&$k=$v";
}
// If available, use CURL
if (function_exists('curl_version')) {
    $to_nexmo = curl_init($this->nx_mkt_uri);

    curl_setopt($to_nexmo, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($to_nexmo, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($to_nexmo, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

    if (!$this->ssl_verify) {
        curl_setopt($to_nexmo, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    }

    $from_nexmo = curl_exec($to_nexmo);

    curl_close($to_nexmo);
}
```

Response:

```
{message-count: "1", messages: [{status: "101", error-text: "Invalid Account for Campaign"}]}
message-count
:
"1"
messages
:
[{status: "101", error-text: "Invalid Account for Campaign"}]
0
:
{status: "101", error-text: "Invalid Account for Campaign"}
```

What is possible solution??

Answer (score 0):

The response indicates that the API key being used is not linked to a Campaign.

For example, if you have two API keys on your Nexmo account with a shortcode Campaign active on your first API key and you are making a request with the second API key, if this second API key does not have a Campaign associated with it, you would receive the 101 response mentioned.

I'd recommend checking with Nexmo support to verify this for you.

[disclaimer: I am a Nexmo employee]